# SetOnItemClickListener error in TabbedActivity with fragments

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-tablayout

So, I have a tabbed Activity called "Onglets". There I created 2 fragments ( OngletCours and OngletNotes).

In OngletCours I have a ListView, and I want to be able to swap to my 2nd fragment (OngletNotes), the name of the Item I clicked ( setonItemClickListener). But when I click on an Item, it doenst go to my 2nd fragment. It remains in the 1st fragment but the content of the 2nd Fragment appears in my current Fragment (OngletCours). I mean, I want to go the 2nd tab when I click on an Item of my listView in my 1st tab

Before clicking on an Item, my app looks like this :

[Before clicking on an Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLaqS.png)

After clicking on an Item you can see that the text "Onglet des résultats", is inserted at the top. But I dont want that. I want to go to the 2nd tab "Notes".
[After clicking on an Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMRKo.png)

Here's the code from my TabbedActivity

**Onglets.java**
public class Onglets extends AppCompatActivity {

```
DatabaseHelper dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_onglets);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_onglets, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ongletcours, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;

    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */

//méthode qui retourne une Fragment qui correspond à chacun des onglets
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        //switch qui retourne la position des différents Onglets
      switch (position){
          case 0:
              OngletCours onglet1 = new OngletCours();
              return onglet1;
          case 1:
              OngletNotes onglet2 = new OngletNotes();
              return onglet2;
          default:
              return null;
      }
    }

    //méthode qui retourne le nombre d'onglets disponibles
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 2;
    }

    //méthode qui sert à définir un titre à chaque Onglet
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "COURS";
            case 1:
                return "NOTES";

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Here's the code of the 2 fragments.

**OngletCours.java** ( I only show you the setOnItemClickListener, because it's where the problems appear)

```
ListView l1 = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ListCours);
    //ce Listener permet de détecter si on clique sur un élément de la liste
    l1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            OngletNotes targetFragment = OngletNotes.newInstance();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_holder, targetFragment)
                    .commit();
        }

    });
```

**OngletNotes.java**

```
public class OngletNotes extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ongletnotes, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    public static OngletNotes newInstance() {
        OngletNotes fragment = new OngletNotes();
        // put values which you want to pass to fragment
        // Bundle args = new Bundle();
        // fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve this and thank you in advance !

Comment: Do you use viewpager to swtich between 2 fragments?

Comment: Yes. But I'll edit my question and insert the code from the TabbedActivity, wait a second pls.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this method to trandfer the data from the one fragment to another

```
   //Put the value
YourNewFragment ldf = new YourNewFragment ();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("YourKey", "YourValue");
ldf.setArguments(args);

//Inflate the fragment
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, ldf).commit();
```

In onCreateView of the new Fragment:

```
    //Retrieve the value
String value = getArguments().getString("YourKey");
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I'll try it later, but first I need to swap correctly between my tabs..

Comment: OK dude.Try it urself

Answer (score 0):

> After clicking on an Item you can see that the text "Onglet des
>   résultats", is inserted at the top. But I dont want that. I want to go
>   to the 2nd tab "Notes"

You create 2 fragments at the same time, so, your fragment `OngletNotes` is initiazlied and you can pass data from fragment `OngletCours` to the second fragment. You create a method `changeData(String data)`.
   YOu code above create another fragment abvove current fragment, so the image 2 like you see

```
public class OngletNotes extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ongletnotes, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    public static OngletNotes newInstance() {
        OngletNotes fragment = new OngletNotes();
        // put values which you want to pass to fragment
        // Bundle args = new Bundle();
        // fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

public void changeData(String data)
     //  DO something
}
```

Now, after you handle click listener from fragment `OngletCours`, you can pass data to fragment `OngletNotes`

```
l1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            OngletNotes fragment = ((Onglets)getActviity())getOngletNotes ();
            if(fragment != null) {
             fragment.changeData("Set you value to send here");
            }
           ((Onglets)getActviity()).goToFragment(1);
        }

    });
```

In you `Onglets` Activity

```
   public OngletNotes getOngletNotes () {
            return (OngletNotes ) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
                    "android:switcher:" + R.id.viewPager + ":" + 1);
        }

public void goToFragment (int index) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(index)
                    }
```

Comment: And where do I insert that method ?

Comment: I write above. Which method are you asking?

Comment: I mean, public OngletNotes getOngletNotes(){...}

Do I insert it in OnCreate method of my Activity ?

Comment: That 's a method, cannot  insert inside another method, add it anywhere in your `Onglets Activity` the same level with other methods. If you are new with Java/Android, you need see some basic class, method, ... to start.

Comment: I was just asking that because when I insert it, it doesn't recognize R.id.viewPager.. (Cannot resolve symbol". Any idea ?

Comment: Change to id of your viewpager. Change ` R.id.viewPager` to `R.id.container`. I  don't see your viewpager.

Comment: Yes. I solved that error. But I still can't swap of tab when I click.
the setOnItemClickListener is inserted in onCreateView, is right, isn't it ?

Comment: You can set viewpager.setCurrentItem( num )  in your Activity to change to the page `OngletNotes`. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you, it's working, but how do I manage to send to the other fragment the Item i clicked on ?

Comment: YOu can find another fragments in viewpager by method `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
                    "android:switcher:" + R.id.viewPager + ":" + index);` with index is the index of the fragment in viewpager. Activity will manage fragments, you can communicate between fragments through activity.